# Permission denied error while reading openssl.cnf file

Tags: powershell, openssl, csr

I am trying to generate SSL certificate via powershell and using openssl for it.
Below is my code:

```
Function new-csr {
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
 $country, #2 please enter char country code
 $state, #state 
 $locality, #city
 $org, # organization name
 $ou, # orhanization unit name
 $cn, # common name  hostname
 $email, # contact email
 $randPath, # path for file
 $privateKeyPath, # path to private key
 $csrPath # path to certificate signin request (output) 

)

# if private key has not been created , create one
if(-not (Test-Path $privateKeyPath)){
    openssl genrsa -out $privateKeyPath 2048
}

if(-not(Test-Path $randPath)){
    openssl rand -out $randPath
}

$subject = "`"/C=$country/ST=$state/L=$locality/O=$org/OU=$ou/CN=$cn`""

openssl req -new -key $privateKeyPath -rand $randPath -subj $subject -out $csrPath
}
```

When trying to execute it in PowerShell under Admin permission. I get permission denied error.
My guess is this might be due to the fact that .cnf file is under Program Files. So should i try uninstalling PowerShell and install again this time outside Program Files folder?

> Can't open C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\cnf for reading, Permission denied
> 9604:error:02001005:system library:fopen:Input/output error:crypto\bio\bss_file.c:69:fopen('C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\cnf','rb')
> 9604:error:2006D002:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:system lib:crypto\bio\bss_file.c:78:
> 9604:error:0E078002:configuration file routines:def_load:system lib:crypto\conf\conf_def.c:170:
> 9604:error:02001005:system library:fopen:Input/output error:crypto\bio\bss_file.c:69:fopen('C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\cnf','r')
> 9604:error:2006D002:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:system lib:crypto\bio\bss_file.c:78:

For OpenSSL configuration, I have added both environment variable as well as user variable:

> EnvironmentVariable: Path as
> C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin
> UserVariable as
> OPENSSL_CONF= C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\cnf

Comment: Is your config file itself `...OpenSSL-Win64\bin\cnf`, which looks like a directory? The file usually is `...\openssl.cnf`.

Answer (score 4):

Running the cmd as `Administrator` worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. The issue is if you are using company laptop Or VPN. Most probably you will face permission issue accessing files inside Program Files folder.

> I uninstalled OpenSSL and reinstalled it outside the Program Files folder. Make sure it's installed outside Program Files.

This worked for me. I am able to create CSR.