# Powershell: New-Item : Access to the path 'influxdb' is denied

Tags: powershell, influxdb

I am trying to follow the official website to use the following command on Powershell to install influxdb:

```
wget https://dl.influxdata.com/influxdb/releases/influxdb-1.8.10_windows_amd64.zip -UseBasicParsing -OutFile influxdb-1.8.10_windows_amd64.zip
Expand-Archive .\influxdb-1.8.10_windows_amd64.zip -DestinationPath 'C:\Program Files\InfluxData\influxdb\'
```

But I get the following error:

```
New-Item : Access to the path 'influxdb' is denied.
At
C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive\Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive.psm1:318
char:32
+ ... eatedItem = New-Item -Path $DestinationPath -ItemType Directory -Conf ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Program Files\InfluxData\influxdb\:String) [New-Item], Unauthorize
   dAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateDirectoryUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand
```

May I know why and how I can fix this problem? Thank you

https://portal.influxdata.com/downloads/

Comment: Seems pretty straight-forward - you either don't have access to write to `C:\Program Files`, or you didn't launch powershell elevated (right-click -> Run as Administrator, or `Start-Process powershell -Verb RunAs`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Permission denied error while reading openssl.cnf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64690201/permission-denied-error-while-reading-openssl-cnf-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `Expand-Archive` command. It attempts to extract the downloaded archive to a subfolder in `C:\Program Files`, but your user account does not have write permissions to this folder (which is by design).

The easiest way to work around this would be to run the command from an elevated PowerShell session (open PowerShell with "Run as Admin").

Comment: running from an elevated PowerShell does not solve the problem, path access still denied